Unique Approach to Solving Coupon Collector Problem
Say there are N types of coupons. Each time we obtain a new coupon, it has an equal probability of being any one of these types. I am interested in finding the probability that it takes n coupons to receive all types.
My approach:
We require the first n-1 coupons to to have exactly N-1 types, with the Nth type received on the nth coupon. To find the probability of such an event, I believe we have N possible "missing" coupon types from the first n-1 coupons. We can then multiply by the probability:
$$P(C_1 C_2 \dots C_{N-1})$$
where $C_i$ represents the probability that there is at least one coupon of type i in the first n-1 coupons. I wanted to calculate this probability using the inclusion-exclusion principle:
$$1 - P(C_1' \cup C_2' \cup \dots \cup C_N')$$
$$ = 1 - \left[ \binom{N-1}{1} \left( \frac{N-2}{N} \right)^{n-1} - \binom{N-1}{2} \left( \frac{N-3}{N} \right)^{n-1} + \dots + (-1)^{N-1} \left( \frac{1}{N} \right)^{n-1} \binom{N-1}{N-2} \right]
$$
$$= 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} \binom{N-1}{i} \left( \frac{N-i-1}{N} \right)^{n-1} (-1)^{i+1}$$
The expression starts with $$\left( \frac{N-2}{N} \right)^{n-1}$$, because we cannot choose the last coupon type as well.
Finally, I compute $$(1 - P(C_1' \cup C_2' \cup \dots \cup C_N')) * N * 1/N$$, where the N again represents the possible missing coupons, and 1/N is the probability that the last coupon is the missing one.
I am getting an incorrect numerical answer with this approach, could someone help by pointing out what is exactly missing or wrong about my answer. Thanks!

When you see my answer, you will notice that I did not attempt to directly diagnose your work.  Instead, I simply provided long-winded step-by-step analysis for your review.  Contrast my style with yours.  It seems to me that if you want a reviewer to directly diagnose your work, then you should adopt a style that is easier to digest.

I will follow in the OP's (i.e. original poster's) footsteps, because I regard their approach as both valid and viable.  So, the OP's question will be answered by having the OP comparing their work with my step-by-step work.
Index the coupons Coupon-1, Coupon-2, ..., Coupon-N.
Since any of the coupons can be the last coupon taken, reserve the factor of $~\displaystyle \binom{N}{1},~$ and then assume that in the first $~(n-1)~$ coupons, that all coupons except Coupon-N have been acquired.
So, now with the factor of $~\displaystyle \binom{N}{1},~$ reserved, you are computing the probability that each of the following events have occurred.

None of the first $~n-1~$ coupons obtained are Coupon-N. 
The probability of this occurring is $~\displaystyle \left[ ~\frac{N-1}{N} ~\right]^{n-1}.~$

The $~n$-th coupon obtained is Coupon-N. 
The probability of this occurring is $~\dfrac{1}{N}.~$

Given that none of the first $~n-1~$ coupons obtained are Coupon-N, that each of Coupon-1, Coupon-2, ..., Coupon-(N-1) were obtained among the first $~n-1~$ coupons.  I will express this probability as $~\dfrac{A}{B},~$ which will be explained later.


Therefore, the final computation will be
$$\binom{N}{1} \times \left[ ~\frac{N-1}{N} ~\right]^{n-1} \times \frac{1}{N} \times \frac{A}{B}. \tag1 $$
So, the problem reduces to computing the fraction $~\dfrac{A}{B}.$

Inclusion-Exclusion is certainly feasible here.  See this article for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see this answer for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion formula.
Following the syntax in the second link, directly above:

Let $~S~$ denote the set of all possible (equally likely) ways of obtaining $~(n-1)~$ coupons.

For $~k \in \{ ~1,2,\cdots,N-1\},~$ 
let $~S_k~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that represents all possible ways of obtaining $~(n-1)~$ coupons, where Coupon-k is never obtained.


Then, the computation of $~\dfrac{A}{B}~$ may be represented by :
$$A = |~S~| - | ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_{N-1} ~|, ~~~~B = (N-1)^{n-1}. \tag2 $$
So, the entire problem reduces to computing $~A.~$

Let $~T_0~$ denote $~\displaystyle | ~S ~| \implies T_0 = (N-1)^{n-1}.$
Let $~T_1~$ denote $\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq N-1} | ~S_{i_1} ~|.~$ 
That is, $~T_1~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{N-1}{1}~$ terms. 
By considerations of symmetry, each term equals $~([N-1]-1)^{n-1}.~$ 
Therefore, $~\displaystyle T_1 = \binom{N-1}{1} \times ([N-1]-1)^{n-1}.$
For $~r \in \{2,3,\cdots,N-1\},~$ 
let $~T_r~$ denote $\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq N-1} | ~S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r} ~|.~$ 
That is, $~T_r~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{N-1}{r}~$ terms. 
By considerations of symmetry, each term equals $~([N-1]-r)^{n-1}.~$ 
Therefore, $~\displaystyle T_r = \binom{N-1}{r} \times ([N-1]-r)^{n-1}.$
Then, by Inclusion-Exclusion theory, the expression for $~A~$ shown in (2) above is equivalent to
$$\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} (-1)^r T_r
= \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} (-1)^r \left[ ~\binom{N-1}{r} \times ([N-1]-r)^{n-1} ~\right]. \tag3 $$

Putting (1), (2), and (3) above together, the final computation is
$$\binom{N}{1} \times \left[ ~\frac{N-1}{N} ~\right]^{n-1} \times \frac{1}{N} \times \frac{1}{(N-1)^{n-1}}$$
$$\times \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} (-1)^r \left[ ~\binom{N-1}{r} \times ([N-1]-r)^{n-1} ~\right]$$
$$= \left[ ~\frac{1}{N} ~\right]^{n-1} \times \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} (-1)^r \left[ ~\binom{N-1}{r} \times ([N-1]-r)^{n-1} ~\right].$$
